# How to prevent submit button being pressed twice

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

I am trying to prevent the users of a system to not press the “Submit” button twice within Oracle ApEx but am unsure how to target the following code using jQuery, i.e.:

```
<a href="javascript:doSubmit('MY_SUBMIT')">
<img border="0" id="MS_BTN" alt="Submit Request" src="submit_btn.gif">
</a>
```

I basically want to make sure that all required form validation has passed and when the user presses the “Submit” button, I would like to somehow hide the button immediately after it has been pressed.

I have tried the following code as I cannot use the src value, i.e.:

```
$("a:contains('MY_SUBMIT')").hide();
```

But this did not work.

How can I add this button to an onclick event and basically hide this button from the user on the successful initial click?

Comment: Hi, I am not able to add an id to the anchor tag but I can to the img tag - can this img id tag be used by any chance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example how to do this with jQuery:

HTML:

```
<a id="mySubmit" href="#">
<img border="0" alt="Submit Request" src="submit_btn.gif">
</a>
```

Code (run after document has loaded):

```
$("#mySubmit").click(function(event) {
    $(this).hide();
    // do other stuff here
    return(false);
});
```

And, a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/CtpLU/

Or, you could do it with only the image and no `<a>` tag like this:

```
<img id="mySubmit" border="0" alt="Submit Request" src="submit_btn.gif">

$("#mySubmit").click(function(event) {
    $(this).hide();
    // do other stuff here
    return(false);
});
```

Other possible solutions besides hiding the button are:

1. To set a flag that you've already submitted and don't do it a second time.
2. Record the time of last submit and don't allow two submits within some period of time (like within 5 minutes).
3. Unbind the event handler so clicking the submit button no longer does anything.
4. Code the server to ignore two submits from the same client within some time period.

Comment: Perhaps you should add event.preventDefault(); -- this is preferable to return false; in this context.

Comment: Appreciate your help but instead of an id in the anchor, I have added an id to the img tag. Can this still be used?

Comment: @Foxtrot - returning `false` in jQuery causes jQuery to automatically do both `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()`.  Why is that not acceptable here?

Comment: @tonsils - if you have an id on the image tag, you can just get rid of the `<a>` tag entirely and just detect the click on the image.  I added an example of that to my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 - appreciate your help. Will try out your new example and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe set a global var that changes when the link is first clicked

```
var clicked = false;

function doSubmit(){
  if(clicked) return;
  clicked = true;

  // all of your code //

  clicked = false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for not using jQuery or another library. "Developers" become much more laisy with such libraries!

Comment: @NikolayIvanov heh, I actually prefer to use JQuery, but there was no need for it here.

Answer (score 1):

Provide some ID to the anchor tag and then you may use the following code

```
$('#anchorTagId').unbind('click.submit').bind('click.submit', function (){
  $(this).unbind('click.submit');
  $(this).hide();
  doSubmit('MY_SUBMIT');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing would be to add an ID to the `<a>` element, otherwise target the image parent somehow:

```
$("img[src='submit_btn.gif']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Any attribute can in theory be targeted, even the "alt" attribute.